# linux redirect localhost port to url port

Tags: linux, docker, redirect, localhost

I need to redirect `localhost:8080` to `http://url:8080/`.

Some background:

I am using docker swarm stack services. One service (MAPS) creates a simple http server that lists xml files to port 8080 and another service (WAS) uses WebSphere Application Server that has a connector that uses these files, to be more precise it calls upon a file `maps.xml` that has the urls of the other files as `http://localhost:8080/<file-name>.xml`.

I know docker allows me to call on the service name and port within the services, thus I can use `curl http://MAPS:8080/` from inside my WAS service and it outputs my list of xml files.

However, this will not always be true. The prod team may change the port number they want to publish or they might update the `maps.xml` file and forget to change localhost:8080 to MAPS:8080.

Is there a way to make it so any call to localhost:8080 gets redirected to another url, preferrably using a configuration file? I also need it to be lightweight since the WAS service is already quite heavy and I can't make it too large to deploy.

Solutions I tried:

- **iptables**: Installed it on the WAS service container but when I tried using it it said my kernel was outdated
- **tinyproxy**: Tried setting it up as a reverse proxy but I couldn't make it work
- **ncat with inetd**: Tried to use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182460) solution but it also didn't work

I am NO expert so please excuse any noob mistakes I made. And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to redirect localhost to another location as it might disrupt your local environment in surprising ways. Many packages depend on localhost being localhost :-)

it is possible to add MAPS to your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts`) giving it the address of maps.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that many times the address of MAPS service isn't always the same. For example, I once got that it had the IP 10.0.0.3 and once the stack was destroyed and restarted it had the IP 10.0.0.5.

Comment: True because of docker swarm, so that would mean that you should have a good install guide and upgrade guide so that the xml file will not be changed and the servername not be changed without due process...

Comment: My main objective with mapping `localhost:8080` is to allow the devs to update the maps files if needed without having to change the formatting. However, changing the urls of the `maps.xml` file and the configuration of the WAS service is a possible solution and I will consider it if nothing else can be done.